# Visual Studio Team Services build error: The given path's format is not supported

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-cloud-services

I've got asp mvc project which is being built successfully within Visual Studio Online Builds environment.

After converting it to Azure Cloud Service and running Build I get the following error:

```
Creating directory "C:\a\1\s\src\Deployment\MYPROJECT.Web.Mvc.Azure.Dev\obj\Release\MYPROJECT.Web.Mvc\C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\Temp".
##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.9\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets(2790,5): Error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs" to "C:\a\1\s\src\Deployment\MYPROJECT.Web.Mvc.Azure.Dev\obj\Release\MYPROJECT.Web.Mvc\C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs". The given path's format is not supported.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.9\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets(2790,5): error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs" to "C:\a\1\s\src\Deployment\MYPROJECT.Web.Mvc.Azure.Dev\obj\Release\MYPROJECT.Web.Mvc\C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs". The given path's format is not supported. [C:\a\1\s\src\Deployment\MYPROJECT.Web.Mvc.Azure.Dev\MYPROJECT.Web.Mvc.Azure.Dev.ccproj]
```

*Azure SDK v2.9, Target framework 4.5.2*

Please note that build is successful when:

1. BuildConfiguration variable is **debug** (instead release)
2. Azure Cloud Service project with new MVC Web Role created from scratch

Comment: The problem looks to come from some copy step of the assembly attributes: You can see that in the second line here where `C:\ ` reappears in the path obj\Release\MYPROJECT.Web.Mvc\C:\Users\buildguest\

Comment: I can't reproduce that issue. My steps: 1. Create a MVC 4 project. 2. Right click project=>Convert=>Convert to Microsoft Azure Cloud Service Project. 3. Add solution to VSTS source control. 4. Create build definition with Visual Studio build template. 5. Queue build.  How did you convert MVC project to Azure Cloud Service? You can share a simple projects on the OneDrive, we will check it.

Comment: What's the details of your build steps? Provide the detail steps and build log here.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue at my side. Can you provide the detailed steps for this issue?

Comment: by default 'Build solution for .ccproj' was configured in the following way: Platform: $(BuildPlatform) and Configuration:  $(BuildConfiguration). Without these settings (just clear them) there isn't problem related 'Creating directory'.

Comment: @СергійКислий What's the detail of your build log? Could you share a simple project on the OneDrive?